# Row a Trend Switches Up or Down

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

Not sure which functions or combination of possibly vlookup, index, match, or aggregate will work best for this.  So far I have spent more than two weeks and can't seem to determine what works.  SO, thank you greatly for the one who can figure this puzzle out.

My goal is to determine how to write a formula that will show these results. My guess is that second formula etc. will be different from the initial as it will start with the row specified from the initial formula as we are interested in knowing what row a trend begins moving up or down based on the given change value.

Based on change of value .15
Results need to be:

13 Up (initial formula)
23 Down (continuing from row 13 ???)
Etc.

Based on change of value .10
Results need to be:

13 Up (initial formula)
17 Down (continuing from row 13 ???)
19 Up (continuing from row 17 ???)
Etc.

Hopefully I am explaining this well.  Thank you, thank you, thank you to the person who can figure this out.

1   277.54
2   277.50
3   277.43
4   277.47
5   277.49
6   277.50
7   277.40
8   277.39
9   277.44
10  277.42
11  277.36
12  277.28
13  277.23
14  277.50
15  277.54
16  277.55
17  277.58
18  277.56
19  277.46
20  277.57
21  277.60
22  277.67
23  277.71
24  277.67
25  277.43
26  277.35

Here is one of my many attempts. =AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(1:26)/(($A$1-A2:A26)>=$I$1),1)+1

First row of >= to .15 difference (row 8) is not adequate
[Image showing inadequate result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mpgo.jpg)
Because the uptrend based on a change of .15 actually started up at row 13.
[Correct example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBzNV.jpg)
Image of what it should look like:
[What it should look like image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTFPh.jpg)

Comment: can you upload a pic of how your sheet should look, to know exacly what the formula should do, as your data and that chart?

Comment: Thank you!  Image uploaded.

Comment: I have some questions: in your example you get up on 13 and I think you're telling that the first change above .15 diff is from 13 to 14. if i'm right your next change should be down on 24, not 23, so what you really need is to get the row with the change >= required, or you need to return the row where the trend actually started?

Comment: Sorry to keep you waiting for answer.  So, if the change value is set at .15 which it currently is, row 13 (277.23) is the point at which the trend switches to an up direction.  You will notice that all the way from row 13 to row 1 the trend never drops by >= .15, so that means row 13 is where it switches direction to up.  Now, if the latest direction is up, then we know the next point or row we are looking for from row 13 is where it switches to down.

Comment: ok I have a way to solve, but you need to use more two columns to do it (you can hide them though)

Comment: That will be fine.  As much as I would like to not need a helper column I was told by someone that I would probably need one or more.

Answer (score 0):

Well finally I have an answer. You will need two more columns to do it on my way (which I think you can hide).

***First step -*** To know when a new trend starts, put this formula in your B2 and pull down till B26
    =IF(A1-A2)(A2-A3)<0,IF(A2-A3<0,"Up","Down"),"")
Now you have on B exacly when started a new trend and which trend*

**EDIT: Now use this formula on B2. After, you need to pull it also to B1 to generate data, and pull down until B26). After pull to B1, don't pull down directly from B1, because there will be an error in the formula, always pull from mid rows formulas. You need to close it with ctrl+shift+enter**

```
=IF(OR(ROW(A2)=SMALL(ROW($A$1:$A$26),1),ROW(A2)=LARGE(ROW($A$1:$A$26),1)),"tail",
IF((A1-A2)*(A2-A3)<0,
IF(ABS(A2-INDIRECT("A"&LARGE(IF(LEN($B$1:B1)>0,ROW($B$1:B1),""),1)))>$K$1,
IF(A2-INDIRECT("A"&LARGE(IF(LEN($B$1:B1)>0,ROW($B$1:B1),""),1))<0,"Up","Down"),
""),
"")
)
```

***Second step -*** To know when your value jumped >= than the value you input in cell K1 (e.g 0.15), put this formula in your C2 and pull down till C26 (close it with ctrl+shift+enter, it's an array formula)
    =IF(ABS(A2-A1)>=$K$1,LARGE((1(LEN($B$1:$B$26)>0))*((1*ROW($B$1:$B$26)0,IF(ABS(A2-INDIRECT("A"&LARGE(IF((1*(LEN($B$1:$B$26)>0))*ROW($B$1:$B$26)>0,(ROW($B$1:$B$26)=$K$1,ROW(A2),""),"")*

**ANOTHER EDIT: Instead, close this formula with ctrl+shift+enter in C2 cell and pull down till the last**

```
=IF(B2<>"",IF(INDIRECT("B"&SMALL(IFERROR(IF(LEN(B3:$B$26)>0,ROW(B3:$B$26),""),""),1))<>B2,B2,""),"")
```

***Third step -*** Arrange data in a list. This is what in your image is in columns D and E. Use these formulas in the first row of any column you want, and pull down as you wish since non utilized cells will just be blank 
    =IFERROR(SMALL($C$1:$C$26,ROW(C1)),"")
and
    =IFERROR(INDEX($C$1:$C$26,E1),"")

**EDIT: now use these formulas below to have the ordered list of changes**

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(LEN($C$1:$C$26)>0,ROW($C$1:$C$26),""),ROW(A1)),"")
```

and

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C:C, F1),"")
```

**As I've put the first of these two formulas on F1 (and pulled down), the second is using F1 as a parameter, but you can put any column you want, just don't forget to change in the index. The first of these two formulas also need to be closed with ctrl+shift+enter, the second doesn't.**

This is how my sheet looks right now (with last changes)

[image]

OBS: Italic parts are "deprecated" in this answer. Only maintaining the text for "log" purposes.

*The first of these two formulas use ROW() as a scapegoat for the number of SMALL's "K" parameter, so you pull down and it will return the first, the second, third, etc, trend changer rows. The other one will pull the matching "up" or "down" information.
OBS: since my Excel is in portuguese and I translated the functions to english using some web dictionary, I may have made some mistakes such as letting semicolon as parameter separators rather than commas. If something goes wrong please let me know and I'll try to fix it.*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176465/discussion-on-answer-by-daniel-souza-row-a-trend-switches-up-or-down).

Comment: Seems I have no additional help.  A good attempt was made, but that was the end of it.  Any suggestions on how to get additional help?  Thanks!